# Unable to add a new component through the experience editor mode in sitecore 10.2 for QA and Dev environments but works fine in the localhost

Tags: experience-editor, sitecore-api

There is an issue we have been facing from a long time. When I try to add a new component through the experience editor in localhost it works fine but if I try the same in QA or dev environment it opens a popup saying `an error has occurred`. With an error in the console that says `"Could not find the rendering in the HTML loaded from server "` but the item is added to the content tree . so I add again the same item by choosing the item from the existing content it is able to add this time. I don't know how to tackle this situation at all

Comment: Is it related? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17589/could-not-find-the-rendering-in-the-html-loaded-from-server-sitecore-experience

Comment: And what is the response from the server when you try to add the component? And what is in Sitecore logs?